# This context with attribute selector on filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```js
var dataid = "2";
console.log(dataid)
var index = $("table thead th").filter(function() {
  return $(this,"[data-id=" + dataid + "]").index();
}).get();
console.log(index)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th data-id="1">1
    </th>
    <th data-id="1">1
    </th>
    <th data-id="2">2
    </th>
    <th data-id="2">2
    </th>
    <th data-id="3">3
    </th>
    <th data-id="3">3
    </th>
  </thead>

</table>
```

I want to filter the **`th`** in my table. I want to get matching data attribute with **`this`** context. My way is not working.

> How to use this context and attribute selector together

`Expected out put`

Get all `th` with `data-id` specified in var `dataid`

Comment: Try to rephrase you question. *"I want to filter the the in my table."*.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Fran get all index with data-id 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your `filter()` is incorrect. You need to return a boolean value indicating whether or not the element matches your requirements. To do this you simply need to check its `data-id` attribute against your `dataid` variable, like this:

```js
var dataid = "2";

var index = $("table thead th").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('id') == dataid;
}).addClass('foo').get();

console.log(index)
```

```css
.foo { color: #c00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th data-id="1">1</th>
    <th data-id="1">1</th>
    <th data-id="2">2</th>
    <th data-id="2">2</th>
    <th data-id="3">3</th>
    <th data-id="3">3</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Note that I also added a class to the elements to show you how you can work with them to amend the UI.

> i want to get index so i used attribute selector. then return the index.

In which case you can use `map()` instead of `filter()` to build an array of the indexes from the required elements, like this:

```js
var dataid = "2";

var indexes = $("table thead th").map(function(index) {
  if ($(this).data('id') == dataid)
    return index;
}).get();

console.log(indexes)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th data-id="1">1</th>
    <th data-id="1">1</th>
    <th data-id="2">2</th>
    <th data-id="2">2</th>
    <th data-id="3">3</th>
    <th data-id="3">3</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to get index so i used attribute selector. then return the index. FYI not my down vote

Comment: So you want to return an array of the indexes of the found elements? In which case you need `map()`, not `filter()`

Comment: sir i have one more question i am using the index to hide the th i tried it directly in map but it is not working how do i use the index from map and hide the th. i am using index because i an dynamically adding td in body i will use the index to hide it as well

Comment: also tried after map i have .each to loop in the index array but it is not hiding other th

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there a benefit using `$(this).data('id')` and `$(this).index()` instead of just using the available parameters and no jQuery object wrapper, such as this `map(function(index, element) {` , `if (element.dataset.id == dataid)` and `return index;` ? Just wondering due to the extra function call on `index()` and wrapping `this` into a jQuery wrapper.

Comment: `dataset` is not available in <IE11, so jQuery's `data()` solves that problem. Other than that it's just about consistency with the use of other jQuery methods.